# Pass the environment in a custom Airbrake notification

Tags: ruby, hoptoad

I've written a custom notification to Airbrake from a Ruby EM server we run along with our Rails app. In the case of an exception, I notify Airbrake as per the API docs

```
 Airbrake.notify(
    :error_class   => "Ruby EM Server Error:",
    :error_message => "EM Server Crashed with error: #{$!}",
    :backtrace    => $@,
  ) if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
```

However, when the error comes through as "Unknown: EM Server Crashed with error:"

I know what the RAILS_ENV is when I send off the notification so I was wondering if there was any way I can pass this info on to Airbrake without writing XML and posting it.

I'd like to see the error to come through as "Production: EM Server Crashed with error:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Airbrake.notify(
    :error_class      => "Ruby EM Server Error:",
    :error_message    => "EM Server Crashed with error: #{$!}",
    :backtrace        => $@,
    :environment_name => ENV['RAILS_ENV']
  ) if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
```

The `environment_name` option is in the gem's [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/airbrake/3.0.9/Airbrake#notify-class_method).

Comment: Thanks mate, that was very kind when all you had to say was RTFM Ganesh! :)